# tezos 11.0-1 fails to start any binary on Ubuntu 18

Tags: node

I have downloaded Tezos binaries from here:

https://github.com/serokell/tezos-packaging/releases

Took binaries-11.0-1.tar.gz, extracted, assigned permissions 755, but when I run any binary, like:

```
./tezos-node --version
```

I get:

```
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

All previous releases I have tried (latest production release was 10.3-1) worked just fine using this method of downloading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means your CPU does not have the required instruction set to run Tezos. There is an ongoing debate around this issue:

https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/issues/1788

The linked issue is about docker, but the overall issue is the same. The dev teams use the latest CPUs available to compile Tezos binaries. Which means, if you have an old CPU (even 2-3 years can be "old") then you might not have certain instruction sets.

Please comment on the issue so we can get the devs to stop doing this.

Comment: Thank you! Commented on that issue and built Tezos 11 from sources so it would work on my machine. For that, first we had to build OCaml because it also is not compatible :)